# On centers of infinite $p$-groups and nilpotent groups

Tags: group-theory, p-groups, infinite-groups

If $G$ is a finite $p$-group, then its center is non-trivial, which forces that $G$ must be nilpotent.

Consider infinite $p$-groups, i.e. infinite groups in which order of every element is some power of (a common prime) $p$. In such a group, we can not say that *center is non-trivial* ([see this example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49349/simplest-example-of-an-infinite-p-group-with-trivial-center)). In particular, I could say that *upper central series of $G$ do not terminates at $G$*.

But, this troubles me to conclude whether $G$ is nilpotent or not? I would like to clarify following things related to this. Please help me.

**Question 1.** What is (are) the definition(s) of *infinite nilpotent group* which can be looked as generalizations of finite nilpotent groups?

**Question 2.** If $G$ is an infinite $p$-group, then what conditions on $G$ would guarantee that $Z(G)$ is non-trivial?

Comment: The usual definition for infinite groups is the same as for finite groups, in terms of the upper central series.

Comment: I am now aware of any sensible answer to Question 2. What type of conditions did you have in mind?

Comment: I couldn't thought about it because of the Tarski-Monster groups.